# Не сохраняется декодированная строка в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка

Декодирую строку этой функцией:

```
function decodeWin(data) {
    const textDecoder = new TextDecoder()
    return textDecoder.decode(Buffer.from(data)).toString('utf-8')
}
```

Затем в эту функцию я передаю объект у которого все значения закодированы.

```
function getDecodedObject(body) {
    let nani = {}

    for (let key in body) {
        const decodedKey = decodeWin(key)
        const decodedValue = decodeWin(body[key])

        nani[decodedKey] = decodedValue
    }

    console.log(nani);
}
```

Теперь внимание! Когда я в цикле вывожу в log(decodedKey) или log(decodedValue), то в логах выходят декодированые значения, но когда я после установки этих значений в объект, смотрю на этот объект, то никаких декодированных значений в нем нету, туда ложатся старые закодированные значения.

Comment: Если это весь скрипт, то в `nani` попадать другие значения, отличные от `decodedKey decodedValue` не могут никак. Меня ваша фраза "туда ложатся старые закодированные значения" наводит на мысль, что функция `getDecodedObject` представлена не полностью.

Comment: `function decodeWin ... const textDecoder = new TextDecoder()` наверное при создании TextDecoder нужно передать какой-то encoding, иначе это - перекодирование из utf-8 в utf-8

Comment: Я клянусь это полная функция, вот такой к примеру объект передаю в getDecodedObject({
  'u\x00i\x00d\x00': '\x001\x003\x00A\x00F\x002\x006\x00F\x00F\x004\x005\x00E\x006\x004\x00E\x00A\x00C\x001\x002\x004\x005\x00'
})

Эти же самые данные и добавляются в "nani", хотя я их декодирую и в самом цикле если смотрю на них, то они декодированные, но как только добавляю их в объект, то закодированные туда записываются. Я сам в шоке, первый раз такое и я шокирован этой логикой.

Comment: @SwaD
Это полная функция. Помоги пожалуйста, что мне сделать в этой ситуации.

Comment: Я кажется понял! Посмеемся )

Comment: @misaki Какой ответ ожидается? { id: 13AF26FF45E64EAC1245 } ?

Comment: @SwaD
да. Такой: {uid: 13AF26FF45E64EAC1245}

Comment: Почему не перекодирует так и не разобрался, однако, консоль.лог преобразует данные перед выводом. Попробуйте у себя в скрипте console.log(key, data[key]). Подумаю на досуге, как это можно преобразовать. в действительности от decodeWin возвращается то же самое значение )

Comment: @SwaD
А я думал логика сломалась. Оказывается console.log автоматом кодирует строки в понятный формат. Короче. Устанавливаем этот пакет для раскодирования и наслаждаемся. npm i iconv-lite
Спасибо за помощь. Так бы долго мне пришлось бы.